# SQL insert #TEMP table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Date  NVARCHAR(256),Pending NVARCHAR(256),Complete NVARCHAR(256) ,Total  NVARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO #TEMP (Date,Pending,Total) 
SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE),'','' from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY DATEE

UPDATE #TEMP
SET Pending=(SELECT COUNT(R_ID) FROM E_R_MainT WHERE STATUS !='S_2' GROUP BY (CONVERT(char(10), HOD_DT ,126)) )
WHERE #TEMP.Date =  (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE) from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY DATEE)

UPDATE #TEMP
SET Complete=(SELECT COUNT(R_ID) FROM E_R_MainT WHERE STATUS !='S_1' GROUP BY DATEE )
WHERE #TEMP.Date =  (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE) from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY DATEE )

UPDATE #TEMP
SET Total=(SELECT COUNT(R_ID) FROM E_R_MainT  GROUP BY (DATEE) )
WHERE #TEMP.Date =  (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE) from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY  DATEE
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

when execute my query i get this error :

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted "

below is my table source:
[image]

i am expecting this output:
[image]

Comment: s_1 = pending,s_2 = complete

Comment: check your subquery manually it should return not only one value but you are updating just only one in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some confusing naming going on here such that I suspect that several names that appear distinct in parts of your query are in fact meant to name the same column(s).

There shouldn't be a need for a temp table here - just use suitable aggregates:

```
SELECT
    DATEE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 's_1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Pending,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 's_2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Complete,
    COUNT(*)
FROM E_R_MainT
GROUP BY DATEE
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is causing issues for you..

```
WHERE #TEMP.Date =  (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE) from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY DATEE)
```

change to..below ,no need of distinct and group by

```
WHERE #TEMP.Date  in  (SELECT (DATEE) from E_R_MainT
```

Comment: hi,i tried the code you give,not working unfortunately ,same error

Comment: that's a sample i gave based on your query for you to modify

Answer (score 0):

This example code from you:

```
UPDATE #TEMP
SET Total=(SELECT COUNT(R_ID) FROM E_R_MainT  GROUP BY (DATEE) )
WHERE #TEMP.Date =  (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE) from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY  DATEE
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

The content of this

```
SELECT COUNT(R_ID) FROM E_R_MainT  GROUP BY (DATEE) )
WHERE #TEMP.Date =  (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEE) from E_R_MainT
GROUP BY  DATEE
```

is not return only one, I thought it returns more than one value, Check all of your query above that look like that. Im sure it is the cause of giving you that error.